# ¿Configurar imageView para que genere imágenes al azar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, array

Ando en un proyecto en **Android Studio** y me he encontrado en un embrollo, necesito hacer que unas 5 imageView que tienen una imagen previa (la cual NO deseo que salga después). La imageView la he generado en mi layout y quiero que la misma genere imágenes al azar al hacer uso de un botón. Espero puedan echarme un cable con esto.

Actualizo, este es mi código, he generado mi array en strings.XML y hasta allí todo correcto pero me genera un error:

> "setBackgroundResource" de la ultima línea... Android Studio me pone
>   "Cannot resolve method 'setBackgroundResource(int)'"

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
    Resources res = getResources();
    final TypedArray myImages = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.myImages);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Random random = new Random();
            int randomInt = random.nextInt(myImages.length());
            int drawableID = myImages.getResourceId(randomInt, -1);
            background.setBackgroundResource(drawableID);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor , que es lo que has realizado, revisa por favor [ask]!, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo si tuviera esas 5 imagenes ya cargadas  por ejemplo en un array  , simplemente , crearia un numero random entre 1 y 5  y elegiria en el load de la actividad que ponga dle array en la posicion del random

Comment: Acabo de hacer algo parecido, pero me lanza un error... He puesto algo de código, espero me eches un cable.

Comment: MyImages.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.NOMBREFOTO),

Comment: deberas tener los nombres de las fotos guardadas en tu array no el entero ,y con eso ya estarias

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, por ahora no puedo comprobar que ande el código aunque debería... Luego de probar de todo un poco modifiqué esa parte del código donde brindaba las imágenes al imageView, pero me marcaba un error en "getResources"... Probaré haciendo uso del código tal cual como lo has puesto a ver que tal me va.

Comment: recuerda tenes tus fotos en drawable , prueba y avisas